# Proper format for copy from with a transaction size in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

What is the proper format for copy from with a transaction size?  I am trying to load 12million rows and getting this error:

```sql
yugabyte=# copy parking_violations from '/home/yugabyte/load_violations.csv' with (FORMAT delimiter ',', csv, header, ROWS_PER_TRANSACTION 10000);
ERROR: syntax error at or near "','"
LINE 1: ...byte/load_violations.csv' with (FORMAT delimiter ',', csv, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is:

```sql
COPY parking_violations from '/home/yugabyte/load_violations.csv' with (FORMAT csv,  DELIMITER ',',  HEADER, ROWS_PER_TRANSACTION 10000);
```

See docs for more: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ysql/the-sql-language/statements/cmd_copy/#import-a-large-table-using-smaller-transactions